# wireless is connected but no internet

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless

i have a new installation of ubuntu (14.04), i installed it with internet via ethernet, and after restart tried using wireless but it says its connected and i cant connect to the internet. im a noob on linux, please help.

$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 [8086:088e] (rev 24)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 AGN [8086:4060]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Comment: Did you unplug your Ethernet cable when tried the wireless network, or disable it in Network Manager?

Comment: @Pilot6 i unpluged it

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run in terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1"
```

and reboot.