# Ubuntu 20.04.1: Wi-Fi stays connected but intermittently loses network access

Tags: wireless, 20.04, dell, iwlwifi

Originally the Wi-Fi was nigh unusable, but I've gotten it to a somewhat working state.
Here's what I've done so far:

- Downloaded the "Hardware Support for Dell Precision 5500" update (fixed the network speed)
- Disabled power management on the Wi-Fi card
- Disabled IPv6
- Checked for drivers on Dell's site based on the service tag, they don't offer anything

The network itself is fine, no other devices are having issues. This is a Wi-Fi 6 network and a Wi-Fi 6 card, as far as I can tell Ubuntu is properly using that as I was able to pull almost 500Mb/s down on speedtest.net. I would test ethernet but I don't have an Ethernet to USB-C unfortunately.

The issue usually only happens once on a fresh boot, after that the network is fine.

My kernel version is 5.11.0-25-generic.

Here's the output from `iwconfig`:

```
wlp0s20f3  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"De Wanna Wanga"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.18 GHz  Access Point: F0:2F:74:91:18:74   
      Bit Rate=2.0412 Gb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-33 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:71   Missed beacon:0
```

And here's the output from `lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network                 
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 14.3
   bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
   logical name: wlp0s20f3
   version: 00
   serial: 8c:8d:28:43:fc:f6
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.11.0-25-generic firmware=55.d9698065.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-55.u ip=192.168.1.15 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:604b11c000-604b11ffff
```

I was trying to see if it was a DNS issue, but when the issue happens even 8.8.8.8 is unavailable:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.15 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

The simple workaround I have right now is simply reconnecting to the network.

NetworkManager logs:

```
    Aug 13 11:08:59 prec5500 NetworkManager[1057]: <info>  [1628867339.6779] policy: set 'De Wanna Wanga' (wlp0s20f3) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Aug 13 11:08:59 prec5500 NetworkManager[1057]: <info>  [1628867339.6783] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: successful, device activated.
Aug 13 11:08:59 prec5500 NetworkManager[1057]: <info>  [1628867339.6789] manager: startup complete
Aug 13 11:08:59 prec5500 NetworkManager[1057]: <info>  [1628867339.9459] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Aug 13 11:09:09 prec5500 NetworkManager[1057]: <info>  [1628867349.8881] agent-manager: agent[91acd221a80c6f5d,:1.83/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
Aug 13 11:14:02 prec5500 NetworkManager[1057]: <info>  [1628867642.7557] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Aug 13 11:19:06 prec5500 NetworkManager[1057]: <info>  [1628867946.9090] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'new-activation', sys-iface-state>
Aug 13 11:19:06 prec5500 NetworkManager[1057]: <info>  [1628867946.9099] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTING
Aug 13 11:19:06 prec5500 NetworkManager[1057]: <info>  [1628867946.9130] device (wlp0s20f3): disconnecting for new activation request.
Aug 13 11:19:06 prec5500 NetworkManager[1057]: <info>  [1628867946.9132] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="62ca0131-6d90-46e1-9daa-d9f904cd015e" name="De Wanna Wanga" pid>
Aug 13 11:19:06 prec5500 NetworkManager[1057]: <warn>  [1628867946.9290] sup-iface[0x55d1eb8cb120,wlp0s20f3]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Aug 13 11:19:06 prec5500 NetworkManager[1057]: <info>  [1628867946.9293] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Aug 13 11:19:06 prec5500 NetworkManager[1057]: <info>  [1628867946.9293] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected
Aug 13 11:19:06 prec5500 NetworkManager[1057]: <info>  [1628867946.9295] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'new-activation', sys-iface-st>
Aug 13 11:19:06 prec5500 NetworkManager[1057]: <info>  [1628867946.9631] dhcp4 (wlp0s20f3): canceled DHCP transaction
Aug 13 11:19:06 prec5500 NetworkManager[1057]: <info>  [1628867946.9632] dhcp4 (wlp0s20f3): state changed bound -> done
Aug 13 11:19:06 prec5500 NetworkManager[1057]: <info>  [1628867946.9648] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Aug 13 11:19:06 prec5500 NetworkManager[1057]: <info>  [1628867946.9651] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: starting connection 'De Wanna Wanga' (62ca0131-d9f904c>
Aug 13 11:19:06 prec5500 NetworkManager[1057]: <info>  [1628867946.9661] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 13 11:19:06 prec5500 NetworkManager[1057]: <info>  [1628867946.9663] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Aug 13 11:19:06 prec5500 NetworkManager[1057]: <info>  [1628867946.9665] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 13 11:19:06 prec5500 NetworkManager[1057]: <info>  [1628867946.9667] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) access point 'De Wanna Wanga' has security, but secrets are re>
Aug 13 11:19:06 prec5500 NetworkManager[1057]: <info>  [1628867946.9667] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 13 11:19:06 prec5500 NetworkManager[1057]: <info>  [1628867946.9668] sup-iface[0x55d1eb8cb120,wlp0s20f3]: wps: type pbc start...
Aug 13 11:19:06 prec5500 NetworkManager[1057]: <info>  [1628867946.9698] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 13 11:19:06 prec5500 NetworkManager[1057]: <info>  [1628867946.9701] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 13 11:19:06 prec5500 NetworkManager[1057]: <info>  [1628867946.9703] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) connection 'De Wanna Wanga' has security, and secrets exist.  >
```

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: you may also want to correct the title and put in the right version number.

Comment: @waltinator there's not really anything meaningful in the NetworkManager logs. I see the point where I reconnected to the WiFi network, but between the initial connection and the reconnection there aren't any fault logs

Answer (score -1):

i had a proplem similar to this and i found the solution that helped me, try excute this command `sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1"`
Reboot after that.
This should work for intel adapters
Or you can find the full question here [wireless is connected but no internet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/668906/wireless-is-connected-but-no-internet)

Comment: Not applicable to this chipset.