# Ubuntu 21.04 connected to wifi but no internet

Tags: wireless, internet, kde, iwlwifi, 21.04

i am new to linux ,i installed kubuntu 21.04 on hp elitebook 8470p  with `Intel Centrino Advanced N 6205 Wifi Card`
but when i connect to my wifi , i cannot access the internet , and my wifi works well with another devices such as my android phone.
So I tested the connection if it was connected correctly, and go to https://192.168.1.1
but i cannot connect to the router settings. i tried to restart NetworkManager Service,
reconnect to the wifi ... etc. But it's totally random, sometimes works , and sometimes no ... Is there any solution ?

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: cannot connect to the wifi settings site.  What is this?

Comment: I tried journalctl command , and there is to warnings
ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist
and the second warning is Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate , i looked for these two files but they is not exist.

Comment: Daivid , i mean the wifi settings , What I am referring to here is that there is an error in my connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly, i solved it.
You can find the answer here
[wireless is connected but no internet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/668906/wireless-is-connected-but-no-internet)
Or just excute this command.
`sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1"`
Reboot after that.
I think this well work for any intel adapter.
If this helped you please tell me.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work for me. I also use protonVPN so it could be the other answer. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

Very similar situation on my ntb, but the root cause was different.
Somenthing went wrong with protonVPN, that caused my ntb not able connect to the internet even connected to wifi.
Solution found here.
[20.04.2 LTS network problem - no internet - but Network status shows connection](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2465968&p=14054957#post14054957)

```
protonvpn configure    (I ran this to see if any parts of the old version of ProtonVPN were still installed)
sudo pip3 uninstall protonvpn-cli   (this was the command to remove the old version - ran it just to ensure I had removed all parts)
sudo apt-get autoremove protnvpn   (this removed the new/desktop version)
rm -rf ~/.cache/protonvpn    (cleaned up desktop version removal)
rm -rf ~/.config/protonvpn    (cleaned up desktop version removal)
nmcli connection show --active
nmcli connection delete pvpn-killswitch
nmcli connection delete pvpn-ipv6leak-protection
nmcli connection delete pvpn-routed-killswitch
exit
```

Comment: Thanks , this can help me later

Comment: OMG this just happened to me. Thank you so much. I didn't have `pip3` installed, so had to skip that step, did everything else, though the only connection I had was `pvpn-ipv6leak-protection`, which did successfully delete. Also there was nothing to exit. Didn't need to reboot though, internet started working right after!